# I have a problem with Chrome's version of SVGGeometryElement.isPointInFill() (works in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, svg

https://jsfiddle.net/awebnoyz/

I need to check for a few thousand paths per second if a point lies within the area.
path.isPointInFill(point) does the trick in Firefox, while Chrome returns false.

I just want to do the check without drawing anything, but chrome only seems to work when the elements are actually added to the document. With appending a path, it takes roughly 100x the time.

Any suggestions?

```
const sPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
sPath.setAttribute('d', "M0 0 L10 0 L10 10 L0 10 Z");
const sPoint = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg").createSVGPoint();
sPoint.x = 5;
sPoint.y = 5;

console.log("virtual:" + sPath.isPointInFill(sPoint));
//chrome:false, firefox:true


//now with actually adding an svg and the path to the document, both return true
svg = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg"))
svg.appendChild(sPath);
console.log("appended:" + sPath.isPointInFill(sPoint));
svg.removeChild(sPath);
```

I am currently out of ideas and using a ray cast instead, which "only" takes 10x time :)

Comment: @Kaiido's canvas/Path2D approach certainly provides the best performance. Worth mentioning: **Webkit** based browsers (e.g apple safari, web/epiphany, midori) also require an element to be attached to the DOM – so Firefox is rather the exception. I've tested timings in this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/LYJOgxx). Results: **Firefox is significantly faster running `isPointInFill()`** (2-3 times faster). Quite strange: in Chrome/Blink browsers, testing "isPointInFill()" for a visible element is ~20% faster than for a hidden element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome does support setting the `d` attribute through CSS, so it makes sense that they don't support this method on elements that are not in the DOM and thus on which all the CSS rules can't be computed.

For what you wish, you can use the [`Path2D(svgString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) constructor along with the canvas 2D  [`isPointInPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) method:

```js
const ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
const path = new Path2D("M0 0 L10 0 L10 10 L0 10 Z");
const pt = { x: 5, y: 5 }
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(path, pt.x, pt.y));
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately

`const path = new Path2D(d);
return ctx.isPointInPath(path, point.x, point.y);`

still performs 50x worse (tested with the 4000 paths) than

`const svgPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
svgPath.setAttribute('d', d)
return svgPath.isPointInFill(point)`

Comment: @JürgenB that's very surprising. Which browser did you run your benchmark on? Could you share that benchmark?

Comment: I finally had the time to do a benchmark and you were 100% right: It is even faster than the SVG method. I only tested it in my application... and i must have made SOMETHING wrong. Because now i made a benchmark with 5000x the same path and it performed well. I put my "real" paths in there: Performance perfect. Than I put it in my application: still perfect. Here is my "real life data"-Benchmark, should someone need it in the future somehow: https://jsfiddle.net/mhv8zejk/4/